# Updating Package Dependencies with New OpenSSL Installation

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, synaptic, openssl

I accidentally deleted some of the files for an existing installation of OpenSSL while installing a newer version of OpenSSL in a different location (neither are the System default installation, which has not been altered). The new version of OpenSSL was installed successfully, and all of the packages that depend on it function normally, but apt and Synaptic have identified the old installation as "broken" and will not permit installation of new packages until the old OpenSSL and all packages that depended on it (which amount to almost 1GB of data) are removed.

How can I get apt/dpkg and Synaptic to acknowledge the new installation of OpenSSL without removing almost every application that used the old one (which is almost every application that has network access)?

Comment: The usual method to restore missing deb-provided files is `sudo apt install --reinstall <package_name>`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the problem by fully overwriting the older installation of OpenSSL.